# NAG library Mark 26 compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I used to have the NAG C Library Mark 23 and I used to compile via

```
g++ -std=c++11  -lm file.cpp -o output.o -I/opt/NAG/clmi623dgl/include 
/opt/NAG/clmi623dgl/lib/libnagc_nag.a -L/opt/NAG/clmi623dgl/lib -lpthread
```

and everything works pretty fine. Now I am using NAG Mark 26 and I am trying to compile with

```
g++ -std=c++11  -lm file.cpp -o output.o -I/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/include 
-L/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/lib -lpthread
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/lib/libnagc_mkl.a  
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/lib/libnagc_nag.a
```

however I receive the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFDictionarySetValue", referenced from:
  _Ff75173be03ba8abe1a864da3d5eb72fd in libnagc_mkl.a(p01zzfn.o)
"_CFNumberCreate", referenced from:
  _Ff75173be03ba8abe1a864da3d5eb72fd in libnagc_mkl.a(p01zzfn.o)

...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

What do I have to do to compile properly with NAG mark 26?

Comment: Certainly move `-lm` to the far right of your command whatever else you do.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is not enough though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution inside the folder NAG/clmi626ddl/scripts:

for the Intel Compiler:

```
icpc -I/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/include 
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/lib/libnagc_nag.a -framework IOKit 
-framework CoreFoundation /Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/rtl/libifcoremt.a 
-lpthread -lc++ -lm file.cpp -o file.o -std=c++11 -O3 -lm
```

for clang:

```
clang -I/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/include
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/lib/libnagc_nag.a -framework IOKit 
-framework CoreFoundation /Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/rtl/libifcoremt.a 
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/rtl/libimf.a 
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/rtl/libirc.a 
/Users/user/NAG/clmi626ddl/rtl/libsvml.a -lpthread -lm -lstdc++
```